# django-filter - add aggregate in filtered data

Tags: django, django-filter

I need to add some counts of my filtered data and i'm using aggregate to do this:

```
class MunicipioList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Municipio.objects.filter().order_by('-id')
    extra_counts = queryset.aggregate(
        cidades=Count('pk', filter=Q(cidade__isnull=False)),
        estados=Count('pk', filter=Q(cidade__isnull=True)),
        estados_aderidos=Count('pk', filter=(Q(usuario__estado_processo=6) & Q(cidade__isnull=True))),
        municipios_aderidos=Count('pk', filter=(Q(usuario__estado_processo=6) & Q(cidade__isnull=False))),
    )
    serializer_class = MunicipioSerializer
    metadata_class = MunicipioMetadata

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = MunicipioFilter
    ordering_fields = ('cidade__nome_municipio', 'estado__nome_uf')

    def list(self, request):
        response = super(MunicipioList, self).list(self, request)
        response.data['cidades'] = self.extra_counts['cidades']
        response.data['estados'] = self.extra_counts['estados']
        response.data['estados_aderidos'] = self.extra_counts['estados_aderidos']
        response.data['municipios_aderidos'] = self.extra_counts['municipios_aderidos']
        return response
```

But the counts are wrong, cause the queryset is not filtered, so it's always based on all objects. I'm using [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter). Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do the aggregate on the filtered queryset:

```
class MunicipioList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Municipio.objects.filter().order_by('-id')

    serializer_class = MunicipioSerializer
    metadata_class = MunicipioMetadata

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = MunicipioFilter
    ordering_fields = ('cidade__nome_municipio', 'estado__nome_uf')


    def get_extra_counts(self): ## in this function first get the filtered queryset then do the aggregate and return it
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        return queryset.aggregate(
            cidades=Count('pk', filter=Q(cidade__isnull=False)),
            estados=Count('pk', filter=Q(cidade__isnull=True)),
            estados_aderidos=Count('pk', filter=(Q(usuario__estado_processo=6) & Q(cidade__isnull=True))),
            municipios_aderidos=Count('pk', filter=(Q(usuario__estado_processo=6) & Q(cidade__isnull=False))),
        )



    def list(self, request):
        response = super(MunicipioList, self).list(self, request)
        extra_counts = self.get_extra_counts() ## get the extra_counts on the filtered queryset
        response.data['cidades'] = extra_counts['cidades']
        response.data['estados'] = extra_counts['estados']
        response.data['estados_aderidos'] = extra_counts['estados_aderidos']
        response.data['municipios_aderidos'] = extra_counts['municipios_aderidos']
        return response
```